# Standard file format for describing hierarchical (nested) finite state machines?

Tags: uml, standards, graphviz, state-machine, scxml

I have a need to describe a hierarchical finite state machine in a standard and portable format. Is there a widely-accepted and supported file format that I should use?

- I see that the [Graphviz DOT language](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) supports sub-graphs that may be referenced by directed edges. (Although rendering connected clusters using Graphviz [is a bit of a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs).) Interpreting the text label on a generic directed edge as a transition event/criterion seems like a slight semantic stretch, but not unusable.
- I see that a [UML Statechart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine) has support for [hierarchically nested states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Hierarchically_nested_states). However, [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930199/standard-uml-file-format) implies that describing a statechart in XMI myself may not actually be properly interoperable with tools that nominally support UML.
- I see the [W3C SCXML Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/). However, this is still a working draft (and has been for almost 7 years), and I'm not certain if any tool supports this format (other than through [conversion](http://code.google.com/p/scxml2dot/)).

Is there a more widely-acceptable alternative than one of the above? Should I use one or the other of the above?

*One of the examples of portability is that I would like for the graph to be able to be read and used by an HSM simulator like [Matlab Stateflow](http://www.mathworks.com/products/stateflow/).*

Comment: FWIW, my company has standardized on SCXML. The standard is quite good, and has been updated since this question was posted, even though it's not quite to Recommended Candidate status yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [OMG standard for UML diagram interchange](http://www.omg.org/spec/UMLDI). But I don't thing it is widely accepted. You can also use the [eclipse EMF UML2](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2) format, for which you can develop yourself translators for other formats.